# Prove the complement of $\operatorname{Col}(A) = \operatorname{Null}(A)$ if $A = A^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried by proving that when $A=A^2$, the complement of $\operatorname{Col}(A)$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Null}(A)$ and vice versa. But I don't know how to use the face that $A$ is idempotent.
How should I approach this question?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

$$x =  x - A(x) + A(x)$$

with $x-A(x) \in \mathrm{Ker}(A)$ and $A(x) \in \mathrm{Im}(A)$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. But I am not sure if I am familiar with the notation Im(A). Can you help?

Comment: $\mathrm{Im}(A)$ denotes the image of $A$, also called the range of $A$ or the column space of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)